# How to trigger `paste` event manually in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event listener which listens on `ctrl - v` paste event. Inside the listener I use `clipboardData.getData` method to get the copied data from clipboard. But now I need to implement a button when users click on that button it does the copy logic. My question is how to trigger a paste event programmatically. The main thing I need to get is the `clipboardData` instance.

Below code is my current `paste` event listener. I need to mock the `e` paste event in order to make the button work.

```
myDom.on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('application/image');

});
```

Comment: Can you provide some of you current logic and script ?

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 13):

> My question is how to trigger a paste event programmatically.

You can't, without the browser having a special setting allowing it (I'm not aware of one that does, and can't immediately find it in Firefox or Chrome's settings) **and** the user enabling that setting. If you could, it would be a significant security problem, because your web page could snoop on the contents of the user's clipboard. That's why you can only get clipboard data from an event object for a clipboard event.

From [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#privacy-events):

> **11.1. Privacy and the Clipboard Event API**
>
> The Clipboard Event API allows scripts running in the context of a clipboard event handler to access a copy of the system clipboard and potentially modify the data being written to the clipboard.
>
> User agents should be aware of the following requirements with regards to securing the data accessed by the Clipboard Event API:
>
> - Objects implementing the `DataTransfer` interface to return clipboard data *must not* be available outside the ClipboardEvent event handler that the data is provided to.
> - If a script stores a reference to an object implementing the `DataTransfer` interface to use from outside the ClipboardEvent event handler, all methods *must* be no-ops when called outside the expected context.
> - **Implementations *must not* let scripts create synthetic clipboard events to get access to real clipboard data (unless the user has configured it to do so).**
>
> Even though the Clipboard Event API is not covered by the Clipboard permission, user agents may choose to provide a method for the user to disable this API or to configure which sites are allowed to access it.

*(my emphasis on the third bullet point)*

Note that the spec does say *"unless the user has configured it to do so"* but again, I'm not aware of a browser that lets the user do that. (Just whether web sites can see clipboard events at all.)

Comment: I still need to implement a custom context menu with "Paste" option in it. Can you give some pointers as to how to implement Paste functionality?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ - Questions should be posted as questions. But FWIW: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Using_the_clipboard Note that it has to be in response to a user action (but a click on some DOM element you've popped up should qualify).

Answer (score 4):

`window.clipboardData.getData('Text');` might work in some browsers, is some browser will prompt the user if they wish their clipboard data to be accessed.