# Capture Paste event in Angular IE11

Tags: angular

I am looking for a solution that allows me to paste what exists in the clipboard when a user click on a button in Angular.

I have used this code to paste data when user type Ctrl+V but I am stucked how to fire this event when user fire the event click on a Button.

```
constructor() {
  document.addEventListener('paste', (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}

copyFromClipBoard(event) {
  // My Code goes here
}
```

Comment: See, if this is of any help to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395393/how-to-trigger-paste-event-manually-in-javascript#51395472

Comment: I saw this post but I was saying if there is any new solution for angular 6 or a new hook to get clipboard data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
copyFromClipBoard() {   
    /// For IE
    if (window['clipboardData']) {
      let value = window['clipboardData'].getData('Text');
      console.log(value);
    }
    else {
      // for other navigators
      navigator['clipboard'].readText().then(clipText => {        
        console.log(clipText);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) to access the system clipboard. The `readText()` method returns a promise that resolves to copied text on the system clipboard:

Template:

```
<button (click)="handleClick()">Click Me</button>
```

Component:

```
handleClick() {
  // using bracket notation as TypeScript may complain about `clipboard` property
  navigator['clipboard'].readText().then(clipText => {
    // do something with copied text here
  });
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc4s2b) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution but unfortunately it does not work on IE11

Comment: You should specify that in your question that you need to support IE11. You should also probably create a StackBlitz or similar to help clarify what kind of element you are working with. You could use the legacy techniques described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Reading_from_the_clipboard). You'd need to probably use element ref to focus on an input/textarea to execute the paste via `document.execCommand("paste")`. Either way, more information is needed regarding your template.

Comment: You are right I will create a StackBiltz next time, it's much better than a simple code.
I have to thank you for your code, I mix it  with IE specification and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do is using `Renderer2` and `ElementRef` from Angular.

You can just inject `Renderer2` in your component/directive and listen to the paste event and do your stuff:

```
constructor(element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

and inside component class listen to the **copy/paste** event:

```
 renderer.listen(element.nativeElement, 'copy', (event) => {
      // do your stuff
    });

    renderer.listen(element.nativeElement, 'paste', (event) => {
      // Do your thing here
    });
```