# Angular: How to get copied URL from clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So this is how I extract the copied text from clipboard:

```
const data = event.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
```

But this code does not work if I copied a URL. The data will be `""` empty. Not sure why is it different with a normal text.

How do I get the copied URL?

---

### EDIT

The event I got is from `paste` event:

```
paste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
  const data = event.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
}
```

From this HTML element (I am using Angular):

```
<div
    id="content"
    contentEditable="true"
    (paste)="paste($event)"
></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is the `event` in your code, but you can get data from clipboard anywhere in your browser via Clipboard API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText

```
const copiedData = await navigator.clipboard.readText()
```

Comment: I am using Angular, the event is from `paste` event from a contenteditable div.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I've read from this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/olawanlejoel/pen/MWGLXyX), the code takes the `textContent` from the quote blocks and then put them all in the clipboard

```
handleCopyClick.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let text = quoteText.textContent;
    let author = quoteAuthor.textContent;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(`${text} ${author}`);
});
```

Adapting to your case though, the code would look something like this:

```
paste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
  let url = urlBlock.textContent;
  navigator['clipboard'].writeText(`${url}`)
}
```

Props to this [FreeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copy-text-to-clipboard-javascript/) for the inspiration.
This one [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077091/capture-paste-event-in-angular-ie11) might also answer some of your questions too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found that the `clipboardData` sometimes hold different types of string. In my code:

```
const data = event.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
```

This only extract `text/html` type.

There are other types like `text/plain`. So this is my solution:

```
let data = event.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
data = data && data.length > 0 ? data : event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
```

If `text/html` is empty, then get `text/plain` data.